# How to prevent cockroaches climbing onto something?

Tags: pest-control, pest, insect

Not much info I could find on what surfaces do cockroaches are unable to climb - nor I have read much into their precise methods of how do they climb stuff, however on this website: https://www.terminix.com/blog/bug-facts/can-cockroaches-climb/ they mention that the following give cockroaches a hard time climbing: Porcelain, Glass, Smooth metal, Granite, Marble surfaces.

So from what I gathered two things came up to me on how to prevent these bastards to climb onto something, in my case - I don't want them to climb up on my bed.

1.) Coat a slippery surface on my normal surface (bed legs, however I don't have bed legs as I have a box bed).

2.) Spray the bed legs (better if you have box bed) with a repellent like pepermint or  eucalyptus, which btw I have no idea how effective these are at all or how long do they last, as the sources where I read this weren't really factual.

Do you guys know any other way on how to prevent them climbing on my bed? If method 1 is ok, what material should I use - I thought of wrapping up transperent tape around my bed but not sure if that counts as slippery. I know it will look terrible, but the crawl of a cockroach shell waking you up and presenting itself to you is far worse image than anything else and a far worse nightmare than the one you were waken up from. I thought about sticking some other material to it, but I really don't know what will work - I have oriental cockroaches why do not fly. Also if anyone tried method 2, is this legit, how long does the effect last for?

Thanks.

Comment: They can also fly short distances. The only way I know is to kill them before they can climb on your bed. Oops I missed you have the ones that don’t fly, do they jump?

Comment: you can make a moat around each leg with a salad bowl. you really should kill them off though, boric acid works wonders for that; cheap and harmless to pets.

Comment: @EdBeal Yeah, oriental are supposed to not be very fly-ledgable, I think they don't jump either. I know, however while I sleep I can't kill them before they come in.

Comment: @dandavis Boric acid is fine (think is not for cats, not sure thought however I don't have any).

Comment: Hire a terminator and apply the pest killer routinely.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boric_acid

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatomaceous_earth

Answer (score 1):

I had a client who had the same problem with the box bed. I put two wraps of foil tape around the frame and it kept those little bast...ds from climbing up. You have to make sure the surface is really smooth and kink free. You can pick up this tape at any home store.

Also, try to bug proof your place. Check for openings around drain and water pipes. Place a few of those "Roach Motels" around the place to kill off some that might already be in. Other than spraying insecticide, which many people don't want to do, I don't know anything else to do. There's a reason they've been around since before the dinosaurs and have survived. Good luck.

Comment: (1/2) Woah, didn't know that dino fact. By foil tape you mean this: https://i.imgur.com/kiPxdbK.png? I don't think I have ever seen that in my life, at least in Europe. Yesterday was a scary day, I found their place if I can call it that, but basically from a drain that is under my sink. I caught one and I sprayed her with raid, she ran there I sprayed there, nightmare afterwards. Roaches kept swarming (not much 1-2 per time) toward anywhere but there, luckily they not that large, and only one was medium sized. So I think they are coming from the sewed, however not sure how - I think..

Comment: (2/2) ... the p-trap there is fine, no smell no nothing - do they swim up?? I am not sure what happens, ventilation, manhole - not sure. I have a lot of other cracks too, I took silicone today and I will caulk everything up, cracks at walll and floor, door frames, everything. Not sure if I should use gel before closing the holes or something like Boric and then just seal it off for good. I also am planning to put some gels on the drains on the floor, close it off with a transperent plastic cup/plate and try to see what happens. The thing is if they come from the sewer, am I screwed?

Comment: If you found where they are coming in I would try and find the foil tape we use it in air ducts on this side of the pond so a hvac/r supplier may have it. The tough part is killing them off once inside. I have read they can survive on a scrap of news paper or any kind of food waste. They say after a nuclear war roaches will be one of the few critters that can survive.+

Comment: @Ed Beal  Roaches and Cher

Comment: @EdBeal I am not sure if I am understanding correctly, you mean I should put this foil tape on the drain on the floor and also on the bed?

Comment: @JACK how do I make sure it is winkle free, do I try to put something above the surface on the box bed? Also is this what I need: https://www.amazon.de/dp/B0049OVT1C

Comment: just keep smoothing it out as you apply it.. no air bubbles or kinks. Here's what I used: https://www.amazon.com/ATack-Aluminum-Reflective-Furnace-metalworks/dp/B07T41VW5W/ref=sr_1_6?keywords=foil+ac+tape&qid=1570549569&sr=8-6

Comment: On the legs of the bed as jack has mentioned. Sealing up the entrance holes at every sink and drain can help to keep them out but now to kill the ones already inside.

Comment: @EdBeal thats the thing cause I have a box mattress it has these little legs and its a bit hard to do it. Before closing the drains, do you recommend me pouring anything?

Comment: I would use poison but that is me. If you use cardboard tubes over the legs then tape the tubes that might help. The tubes that posters come in would be big enough to go around the wheels as a possible idea.